# Errors with BitByteArray

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a 2 dimensional array and I need an eight bit Byte Array because I'm displaying audio waveforms. However I keep getting errors in the eightBitByteArray[t] and the sixteenBitByteArray[t]. Any suggestions on how I could fix this?
I've also tried replacing it with the file name but it doesn't seem to work.

```
    for (int t = 0; t < eightBitByteArray.length;) {
            for (int channel = 0; channel < numChannels; channel++) {
                int low = (int) eightBitByteArray[t];
                t++;
                int high = (int) eightBitByteArray[t];
                t++;
                int sample = getSixteenBitSample(high, low);
                toReturn[channel][sampleIndex] = sample;
```

Comment: you need to add more details, like where is the exception, what is the exception,etc.

Comment: You'll have a problem if your `eightBitByteArray` length is not even, as you're reading two values at a time.

Comment: Given that you increment `t` _twice_ in the loop, you should check that `t` is less than `.length - 1`. Also, what is `toReturn` here?

Answer (score 0):

You don't reset the value of t to 0 anywhere. So my guess would be that you are exceeding the size of eightBitByteArray at some point. You're also not checking if t ever exceeds the size of eightBitByteArray in the second increment of t.

But unless you post more details, like the exception, location, sample input data,etc. its hard to say. Also post some more code.